# Module Disable/Uninstall Issue - Magento 2.4.0

Tags: magento2, extensions, customer-account, extension-attributes

I installed a module, But that was conflicting with the account dashboard, So I uninstalled that module and remove that extension folder from Code. But now my account dashboard is still not working, First, it's working fine but after installation, that module now the issue is coming if I'll use that one then facing minor confliction error and if I uninstall that module then Magento login and register not working properly.

Please check below error is showing in system.log

```
main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Class Sparsh\MobileNumberLogin\Model\Attribute\Backend\MobileNumber does not exist
```

Kindly help me how to I can resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the module added some attributes (customer, product, category or customer address) that you have to cleanup manually.
Ideally you should look through the extension's install scripts and identify all the attributes it added and remove them from the eav_attribute table.

But to strictly fix this issue, look in the eav_attribute table for records with source_model or backend_model or frontend_model equal to `Sparsh\MobileNumberLogin\Model\Attribute\Backend\MobileNumber` and remove them

Comment: Yes, right now i am checking database in eav_attribute, there are few attributes are added.  I am working on that. If i need your help i'll ask in comment.